# Intel DAAL python error

Tags: python, intel-parallel-studio, intel-dal

Intel Data Analytics Acceleration Library (Intel DAAL) has been installed successfully on my ubuntu. However, when running examples located at compilers_and_libraries_2017/linux/daal/examples/python/source/distance, I got following error. Anybody have this problem before?

```
$ source activate intelpython
(intelpython) W2600CR:/compilers_and_libraries_2017/linux/daal/examples/python/source/distance$ 

$ python3.5
Python 3.5.2 |Intel Corporation| (default, Feb  5 2017, 09:07:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Intel(R) Distribution for Python is brought to you by Intel Corporation.
Please check out: https://software.intel.com/en-us/python-distribution
>>> 

(intelpython)$  :/compilers_and_libraries_2017/linux/daal/examples/python/source/distance$ python3.5 cos*.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cos_dist_dense_batch.py", line 48, in <module>
    DataSourceIface.doDictionaryFromContext
  File "/media/liqisuccess/76F07852F0781A97/Ubuntu/App/Anaconda3/envs/intelpython/lib/python3.5/site-packages/daal/data_management/__init__.py", line 4540, in __new__
    return FileDataSource_CSVFeatureManagerFloat64(*args)
  File "/media/liqisuccess/76F07852F0781A97/Ubuntu/App/Anaconda3/envs/intelpython/lib/python3.5/site-packages/daal/data_management/__init__.py", line 3534, in __init__
  this = _data_management.new_FileDataSource_CSVFeatureManagerFloat64(*args)
SystemError: Error on file open
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem. After I dig into the sample source, I found that it's due to the csv file path.

Just cd to compilers_and_libraries_2017/linux/daal/examples/python and run the sample again.